# Concise way to generate multiset lists

Tags: combinatorics, list-manipulation, sets

I wrote the following to generate a multiset with the same number of items over a fixed range:

```
ConstantArray[#, 3]& /@ Range[9] // Flatten
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9}
> ```

This approach uses four named functions (`Range`, `Flatten`, `ConstantArray` and `Map` (`/@`)) and one pure function (ending with `&`).
Is there a way to do the same thing with fewer functions?

Also, if I wanted to have variable numbers of items in my multiset how would I do that?
For example, let's say I wanted a multiset like `{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8 }`.

By a "variable number of items" I do not mean random, I mean a specified variable number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   f[n_, k_] := Table[ConstantArray[i, n], {i, k}]
```

Now you can vary the number of items of each:

```
f[3, 9] // Flatten
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8,
>   8, 9, 9, 9}

```
f[4, 10] // Flatten
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6,
>    6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10}

for random Situation:

```
fRandom[n_, k_] := Table[ConstantArray[i, RandomInteger[{1, n}]], {i, k}]
```

For your second situation try this;

```
Inner[ConstantArray, Range[8], {4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3}, List] // Flatten
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8}

Comment: for constant `k`, one could also do: `Flatten[Table[i, {i, 10}, {j, 3}]]`

Comment: @PinguinDirk. Fo shizzle :)

Comment: I do not want random numbers of items. I want specific numbers of each item in the multiset.

Comment: @TylerDurden, Well, initially you did not specify this. How exactly do you want to specify those numbers, you need to be more specific so we know what you want.

Comment: @TylerDurden. See my update.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. It uses only two functions and is nice and flexible. Also, the solution for the bounded multiset problem is good and comparable to Artes.

Answer (score 11):

**Ad. I**

These should be the most efficient and tersest

```
Ceiling[ Range @ 27 / 3 ]
```

or

```
Array[ Ceiling[#/3] &, 27]
```

yield

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9}
> ```

they both can be tersely written in the `Front End` (see details of `Ceiling`) as:

[image]

or

[image]

**Ad.II**

For the second problem there are  many approaches, here is a solution with a determined number of items ( `Count[{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8}, #] & /@ Range[8]`) as in your example:

```
Inner[ ConstantArray, Range @ 8, {4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3}, Join]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8}
> ```

or

```
Flatten @ MapThread[ ConstantArray, {Range @ 8, {4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3}}]
```

Comment: I do not want random numbers of items. I want specific numbers of each item in the multiset.

Comment: @TylerDurden So you've got it.

Answer (score 6):

To me, the most straightforward way seems to be:

```
Flatten[ConstantArray[Range[9], 3], {2, 1}]
(* {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9} *)
```

i.e., instead of repeating each element in the list 3 times, you repeat the entire list 3 times and flatten it using the appropriate second argument.

Comment: +1 -- this is the same method I use, though usually with infix: `Range@9 ~ConstantArray~ 3 ~Flatten~ {2, 1}` :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Pfft lame... `1 ~Range~ 9 ~ConstantArray~ 3 ~Flatten~ (2 ~List~ 1)` :P

Comment: reductio ad absurdum

Answer (score 4):

No `Rule`s?, so this is one from [Szabolc's site](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php):

```
 Range[9] /. n_Integer :> Sequence[n, n, n]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9}
> ```

---

Since you haven't described how those numbers should vary for second part, maybe something like:

```
Sort@RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 27]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10}
> ```

Ok, let's say you have list of numbers which are referring to consecutive integers repetition:

```
Flatten@MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2, #] &, {4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6}
> ```

Or similar:

```
i = 0; 
Flatten[ConstantArray[++i, #] & /@ {4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6}
> ```

Comment: I do not want random numbers of items. I want specific numbers of each item in the multiset. For example, in the case shown I want four 1's, two 2's, one 3, three 4's, no fives, two 6's, one 7, and three 8's.

Comment: @TylerDurden ok :) see my edit

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[ Range[ 1, 9, {1, 1, 1}], {2, 1}] 
Join @@ Table[ i, {i, 9}, {3}]
Join @@ Array[ # &, {9, 3}]
Table[ 1/9 (3 n - 2 Sqrt[3] Cos[(2 π n)/3 + π/6] + 3), {n, 27}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8,
>       8, 9, 9, 9}

Comment: This answer gets the booby prize, or the tongue-in-cheek prize, as the case may be.

Comment: +1 for the first one; a nice way to use only two functions!

Answer (score 2):

For your second question:

```
MapThread[ConstantArray, {Range[9], RandomInteger[{1, 3}, 9]}] // Flatten
(* {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way, for the first part:

```
With[{n = 3, k = 10}, Quotient[Range[k n], n, -n+1]] (* incorporating Artes' suggestion *)
```

**Updated:**

For the second part, an approach not already covered in the other answers:

```
Module[{i = 1, reps = {4, 5, 1, 3}}, 
   Fold[#1~Join~ConstantArray[ i++, #2] &, {}, reps]] (* reps are variable repetition factors *)
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4}

Comment: Very nice (+1) however I'd rather do this `Quotient[ Range[3  9], 3, -2]` to get exaclty what has been expected. Consider to answer another question in the OP.

Comment: Oh sorry - for some reason I imagined the sequence began with zeros. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Why do you need `With`? There is no need for `Range[1, k n]` since it's equal to `Range[k n]`.  And what about variable number of items?

Comment: Oops, that was a mistake - I was really sleepy when I wrote that. Fixed now. The `With` is just for convenience and generalization, if someone wants to use the same method with a different range or repetition value. (I could've written it as a function.)